# Multiple JPanel GridBagConstraints alignment

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

[image]

As shown in the pic, firstly there are two panels: topPanel and btmPanel.
The topPanel consists of another two panel, one filled with black and one filled with gray
this is not the problem.

In the btmPanel there are three panels which are all in GridbagLayouts, each of the panels have different amount of JButtons
The problem is the third panel have more JButtons so what I want is to align them to start from the top. Is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean align the to start from the top? I think already the buttons start from the top to down?!

Answer (score 2):

When setting the constraints of those 3 panels, make sure to

1. set the GridBagConstraint property `weighty` to something bigger than 0, for example 1.0,
2. and also set the property `anchor` to `NORTH` or `NORTHEAST` or `NORTHWEST`.

Of course, the `fill` property can only be set to `NONE` or `HORIZONTAL`, otherwise all panels will be stretched vertically, which I guess, you don't want.

Here is an example of what I describe. I simplified your case by replacing the 3 big panels with 3 buttons (one of them is taller than the other):

Results (see how 3 buttons are aligned on top):

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestLayout {

    protected void initUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestLayout.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel btmPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        JButton comp = new JButton("Panel-1");
        btmPanel.add(comp, gbc);
        JButton comp2 = new JButton("Panel-2");
        btmPanel.add(comp2, gbc);
        JButton comp3 = new JButton("Panel-3");
        comp3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(comp.getPreferredSize().width, comp.getPreferredSize().height + 10));
        btmPanel.add(comp3, gbc);
        frame.add(btmPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestLayout().initUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is able to work after I setting the anchor.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the Layout for the `btmPanel` to **GridLayout(1, 3, 5, 5);**, that will align them to the top. Since presently the default Layout for the `btmPanel` is FlowLayout, hence you experiencing this issue. On top of this `btmPanel` you have these three `JPanel`s with `GridBagLayout`.

Comment: This will also make all three panels with the exact same size which is not what the OP asked for. And actually FlowLayout would align them on top.

Comment: It will align them to the top side, FlowLayout is not meant for this thingy. FlowLayout will simply put the smallest JPanel towards the center line to accommodate other larger JPanels vertically.

Comment: Ok, my mistake, FlowLayout centers them vertically. Yet, GridLayout will make all three components the same size.

Comment: STill the OP never said anything about the bottom part of alignment, it's all about aligning them towards the top. In the absence of the code, it's hard to say what will actually work, else could've tested it and put the real alternative, that might can look good as a view for the user.